# How to store array data using laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, string, type-conversion

I am trying to store data of another table but it's not working.I am new to laravel.

Please help me guys.

I have table named **external_event_venues** where i have column inside named amenities.

I have another table named **venue_amenities** where i have id as foreign key external_event_venue_id with column name amenity_id.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I assigned relationship between table is like this:
**ExternalEventVenue.php**

```
 public function amenities()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(VenueAmenities::class,'external_event_venue_id', 'id');
 }
```

I have create.blade file inside code for animities :

```
<x-forms.label fieldId="amenity" :fieldLabel="__('modules.venue.amenities')"      fieldName="amenities[]" fieldRequired="true">
</x-forms.label>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap mb-3 ">
       @foreach(config('global.amenities') as $key => $value)
           <x-forms.checkbox :fieldLabel="$value" fieldName="amenities[]" fieldId="{{$key}}" fieldValue="{{$key}}"/>
       @endforeach
</div>
```

I have assigned array for it inside my global.php file :

```
<?php
    return[
          'amenities'  => [1 => 'Beachfront', 2 => 'A/V Equipement', 3 => 'Handicap Accessible', 4     => 'Pet Friendly', 5 => 'Outdoor Space', 6 => 'Breakout rooms', 7 => 'Business Center', 8 => 'Cab', 9 => 'Rooftop',10 => 'Theater space' ,11 => 'Parking' ,12 => 'Media room',13 => 'Spa' ,14 => 'WiFi'],
];
```

I want to store array data using controller method :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
           ...
           $venue->amenities = $request->amenity;
           $venue->save();
           $venue = new ExternalEventVenue();
            if (isset($request->amenity_id)) {
            foreach ($request->amenity_id as $amenityId) 
            {
                if ($amenityId !== null) {
                    $amenity = new VenueAmenities();                    
                    $amenity->amenity_id = $amenityId;
                    $amenity->external_event_venue_id = $venue->id;
                    $amenity->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please anyone can help me with this...

Comment: Are you creating the venue and amenities both as a new entry or are you adding the amenities to an existing venue?

Comment: No. I am sharing screenshot of my table. you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from a simplified database to achieve your goal.

Let's assume we have this schema:

```
venues
    id
    name
    
amenities
    id
    name

amenity_venue (pivot table)
    id
    venue_id
    amenity_id
```

The Venue model:

```php
class Venue extends Model
{
    public function amenity()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Amenity::class);
    }
}
```

The Amenity model:

```php
class Amenity extends Model
{
    // ...
}
```

The magic then happens in the [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) function, which stores the data in the pivot table (amenity_venue) for a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //...

    // if you don't create a new entity here, you have to pass the ID of an existing entity
    $venue = Venue::find($request->venueId);

    // amenities[] are the selected checkboxes as an array
    $venue->amenity()->sync($request->amenities);
}
```

If you follow the naming conventions, Laravel will do all the work for you.